# How to integrate REST API on Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver

I can run the REST API using multiple tools like Soap, curl etc. But I need to integrate REST API developed in JSON format in Selenium WebDriver.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `requests` and call your apis and then decode the response using `json` decoder.